# put and patch method in same viewset and listapi not working

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have defined put and patch method like this in url.

```
url(r'^contacts/$', ContactsViewSet.as_view({"post": "create", "get": "list"}), name="contacts_api_view"),
    url(r'^contacts/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        ContactsViewSet.as_view({"put": "update", "get": "retrieve_details", "delete": "destroy"}),
        name="contacts_instance_api_view"),
```

Still i am only able to call  the put method and when sending patch request its saying method not found.
Below are the the code in **views.py**

```
class ContactsViewSet(ViewSet, ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ContactsSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter)
    filter_class = ContactsFilter
    search_fields = ['name', 'mobile']
    ordering_fields = ['name', 'created_at', 'current_debt']

    def retrieve_details(self, request, pk):
        instance = get_or_none(Contacts, pk=pk)
        if not isinstance(instance, Contacts):
            return error_response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, msg="Contacts does not exist", data={})
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return success_response(status=HTTP_201_CREATED, msg="", data=serializer.data)

    def update(self, request, pk):
        instance = get_or_none(Contacts, pk=pk)
        if not isinstance(instance, Contacts):
            return error_response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, msg="Contacts does not exist", data={})
        request.data["user"] = request.user.id
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, instance=instance)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return success_response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, msg="", data=serializer.errors)
        serializer.save()
        return success_response(status=HTTP_201_CREATED, msg="", data=serializer.data)

    def partial_update(self, request, pk):
        instance = get_or_none(Contacts, pk=pk)
        if not isinstance(instance, Contacts):
            return error_response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, msg="Contacts does not exist", data={})
        request.data["user"] = request.user.id
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, instance=instance, partial=True)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return success_response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, msg="", data=serializer.errors)
        serializer.save()
        return success_response(status=HTTP_201_CREATED, msg="", data=serializer.data)
```

The issue is the post method is executed but patch method i am not able to execute.

Comment: add your complete view class

Comment: class ContactsViewSet(ViewSet, ListAPIView)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu added complete class

Comment: which URL is used to make http put request?

Comment: resolved my bad it was not given in  the urls , patch  method

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in urls.py

```
url(r'^contacts/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    ContactsViewSet.as_view({"patch":"partial_update","put": "update", "get": "retrieve_details", "delete": "destroy"}),
    name="contacts_instance_api_view"),
```